# Hamilton's function according to the Delaunay variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimal-control, hamilton-equations, mathematical-astronomy

Consider the following system:
\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}_1=-\frac{\mu_{\oplus} x_1}{r^3}-\frac{\mu_\oplus R_{\oplus}^2J_2}{r^5}\bigg(\frac{3}{2}x_1-\frac{15}{2}\frac{x_1x_3^2}{r^2}\bigg)\\
\ddot{x}_2=-\frac{\mu_{\oplus} x_2}{r^3}-\frac{\mu_\oplus R_{\oplus}^2J_2}{r^5}\bigg(\frac{3}{2}x_2-\frac{15}{2}\frac{x_2x_3^2}{r^2}\bigg)\\
\ddot{x}_2=-\frac{\mu_{\oplus} x_3}{r^3}-\frac{\mu_\oplus R_{\oplus}^2J_2}{r^5}\bigg(\frac{9}{2}x_3-\frac{15}{2}\frac{x_3^3}{r^2}\bigg).
\end{equation}
where $J_2=1082.6261\cdot 10^{-6}, \mu_{\oplus}=398600.4405km^3s^{-2},r=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}, R_{\oplus}=6378.137 km.$

Give me an idea of how I could prove that this system, which describes the case of a satellite whose motion is disturbed by the non-sphericity of the earth, is a Hamiltonian system and how I could determine Hamilton's function in Delaunay coordinates.
I understand the practical part well, but from a mathematical point of view I do not have a theoretical basis.
Thank you very much !

Comment: I would usually say just multiply the equation for $\ddot{x}_{i}$ by $\dot{x}_{i}$ and integrate and then sum resultant equations together, but I think the presence of the $x_{3}^{2}$ terms complicates the problem. I'll take a look later if no one has already answered the problem. The symmetry $x_{1} \leftrightarrow x_{2}$ might also be useful.